# Typo: bool to int conversion induced error in std::ifstream under Linux

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, ifstream

I had a typo (`||` instead of `|`) and noticed such a code fails with GCC and compiles with Visual. 
I know that the second parameter of `std::ifstream` is an `int`. So theoretically, a `bool` has to be converted implicitely to an `int`. So why it fails?

Example inducing the error (I just used some ints instead of the flags).

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  std::ifstream("foo", 2 | 3 || 4)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::ifstream`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) takes as second argument an [`std::ios_base::openmode`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) which is `typedef`ed from an *implementation defined* type:

```
typedef /*implementation defined*/ openmode;
```

It seems Visual uses integers, GCC does not, and it's why your code fails on GCC.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Regardless of the reason, it seems a bit odd to me. What could be the reason that the type of a standard library function parameter is implementation defined. Couldn't it cause a portability issue?

Comment: @dgrat you're only supposed to use the `openmode` explicitly defined.

Comment: I wonder a bit about all the up-votes of my question. Expected the opposite, because seems like a beginner issue.

Comment: @dgrat when life gives you lemons... I up-voted your question because I didn't know why your code worked with MSVC but not GCC, and it was fun to learn why.